# can't login with twitter using django-social-auth

Tags: twitter-oauth, django-socialauth

I'm using django-social-auth app (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) for social authentication.

I provided the consumer_key and consumer_secret to the app.

when I write the link that logins to twitter 
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/twitter, the page loads, as if there's a request being sent, for some seconds, then page stops loading without any redirecting  or any other reaction

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the Callback URL in your Twitter app settings to point to localhost.

Go to your Twitter app settings:

https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Choose your app and click on the Settings tab.  In the Callback URL field type:

http://127.0.0.1:8000

Once you deploy your app on the web you'll need to return to this screen and update the Callback URL to point to your app's domain.